# Replacing golang error codes with panic for all error handling

Tags: go

We have medium sized application written in go. From all the code lines about 60 percent goes to code error handling. Something like this:

```
if err != nil {
   return err
}
```

After some time, writing this lines over and over again becomes tiresome and  we are now thinking to replace all error codes with panics.

I know panics aren't meant to be used like that.

What can be potential pitfall and does anyone have experience with something similar ?

Comment: Good luck from recovering your injuries incurred during this process. IMHO this is an insane idea.

Comment: Errors are normal values, and it's going to be hard when you start panicking on expected errors like `io.EOF`. Is an if statement really that much harder to type than panic? (BTW, have your editor provide common snippets if you don't want to type them out)

Answer (score 1):

The main pitfall would be a widespread use of hammers to drive screws. *Panic is for unrecoverable/unexpected errors, error return values are for recoverable/expected errors.*

Replace the word "panic" with "crash", because that is conceptually what a panic is. Do you honestly want to write an application that **by design** crashes whenever anything goes in any way remotely wrong? That would be the most fragile application on Earth, the very antithesis of fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

As all the comments suggest you could be signing up for a disaster and let me add, whosoever is going to maintain this code will go insane trying to figure out what exactly went wrong when things do go awry if you don't do proper error handling (even if that person is you, it's going to haunt you).

Just repeating what others have said - the problem is being unable to differentiate between these two

- a predictable & possibly recoverable condition
- perhaps what is unrecoverable (need to exit the application or be handled at a higher level - this may be coming from your own application's conditions or some third party library, but is forcing you out of your normal execution path)

Panics are reserved for the latter types.